# How to filter in datahub graphql?

Tags: graphql, pimcore-v5, ads-data-hub

I’m using the `data hub` function with `GraphQL` to fetch data for external systems, but I have problems with filters for nested objects.

Taking the example of docs, in the products endpoint of the demo, I make this call and I get all cars called E-Type.

```
{
    getCarListing(filter: "{'name' : 'E-Type'}"){
        edges{
            node{
                name
                    manufacturer{
                        … on object_Manufacturer{
                        name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I filter on manufacturer name? I was thinking to this filter:

```
filter : "{'manufacturer' : {'name' : 'Jaguar'}}".
```

This return me column_name `name` not found response.

Can anybody please help me solve this?

Comment: Would be very interesting for me as well

Answer (score 0):

found a response in this ticket: https://github.com/pimcore/data-hub/issues/224#issuecomment-628514018

Here they state, that this feature is currently not supported by PimCore. Maybe it will be supported in the future.